# Setting array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, struct, function-declaration, double-pointer

i'm doing a small exercise to load an array of pointers (double pointer) to a struct. I have the following definition in the header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN (5)

typedef struct sample_s {
    int num;
    char *name;
}sample_t;

typedef struct new_sample_s {
    char *string;
    sample_t **sample_arr;
}new_sample_t;

sample_t table[LEN] = {
    {0, "eel"},
    {1, "salmon"}, 
    {2, "cod"},
    {3, "tuna"},
    {4, "catfish"}
};
```

and using the definitions int this .c file:

```
#include "test.h"

void print_new_sample_array(sample_t **sample_arr) {
    int len = sizeof(table)/sizeof(new_sample_t);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("The array element is: %s\n", sample_arr[i]->name);
    }
}

int main() {

    new_sample_t new_sample;
    new_sample.sample_arr = table;

    print_new_sample_array(new_sample.sample_arr);

    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

First I'm not sure how to correctly load the `table` to the `new_sample.sample_arr`
Error message here:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:13:27: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     new_sample.sample_arr = table;
                           ^
```

Second, I'm not sure how I can refer to the properties of each element in the `sample_arr`. For example, when I do the following, the program errored out:

```
for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++){
    printf("This is the elem in the array: %s", new_sample[i]->name);
}
```

I'm trying to learn more about the double pointer concept and why I did it wrong. I would really appreciate the answer keeps the `sample_arr` as double pointer

Thank you!

Comment: "First I'm not sure how to correctly load the table to the new_sample.sample_arr Error message here:" => you don't, the **type** of `new_sample` is wrong. Try `sample_t *sample_arr;`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I guess a better question should be how to load a double pointer array. Since I'm trying to learn that. I tested with ```sample_t *sample_arr``` it does work, but not necessarily helps me understanding double pointer :)

Comment: You need to start with an array of pointers, e.g. `char *table[] = {"cod", "tuna"};` What you have is an array of `struct`.

Comment: `new_sample.sample_arr` is a pointer to a pointer to a `sample_t` structure, while `table` is a pointer to a bunch of `sample_t` structures. I suggest something like `new_sample.sample_arr = &table`.

Comment: @ImTrying do or do not, there is no try :D You're asking the wrong questions. You don't need a doubly-indirect pointer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this assignment statement

```
new_sample.sample_arr = table;
```

the right operand (after implicit conversion of the array to pointer to its first element) has the type `sample_t *` while the left operand has the type `sample_t **` due to the declaration of the data member

```
sample_t **sample_arr;
```

There is no implicit conversion from the type `sample_t *` to the type `sample_t **`. So the compiler issued a message.

You should declare the data member like

```
sample_t *sample_arr;
```

and correspondingly the function declaration will look like

```
void print_new_sample_array(sample_t *sample_arr);
```

And within the function the call of `printf` will look like

```
printf("The array element is: %s\n", sample_arr[i].name);
```